# How to Access RSS reader in IOS

Tags: ios, rss-reader

I'm using Xcode 5.1 version. I want to use RSS feed for my app. All posts are confusing me.Can anybody help me?
Thanx in advance!

Comment: Why aren't you use `xcode 6.1`? `xcode 5.1` is well out of date now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own code to parse the RSS feed and use items.

You can use this tutorial : http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-rss-reader-tutorial/